# Removing certain files specified in a list

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am going to be using `datetime` library to create a list of dates that are considered "valid". A valid date is a date that is

a) A working Day

b) Less than 14 working days old.

The dates are in format 20140917 - `%Y%m%d`

I then intend to iterate over a list of files and if the file name (which is in identical format) is not in this list, then delete the file.

However I know that deleting anything from the list you're iterating over is bad.

How would I go about this then, because I must iterate over the list of files and my pure intention is to delete some of them.

As a side note, I am also struggling on creating the list of valid dates.

I currently have this snippet from a previous script I wrote, but I can't work out how to use it to create a list of "valid" dates.

```
for (day,name) in itertools.izip((day for day in (datetime.today()+timedelta(n) for n in xrange(20)) if day.weekday() not in (5,6)), (itertools.cycle(names))):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly you have a list with lots of dates. 
From this list you want to filter all dates that are older than 14 days and are not a week day.

This can be archieved by using the **set** and **&** command:

```
list_of_dates = ['0000000', '20140930', '11111111', '20140926', '20140925', '33333333']

# Create valid dates
now = datetime.now()
valid_days = [(now - timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%Y%m%d') for i in range(-14, 0) if (now-timedelta(days=i)).weekday() not in (5,6)]
# filter list
filtered = list(set(list_of_dates) & set(valid_days))
```

This results in the list:

```
'20140926', '20140930', '20140925'
```

Comment: That's perfect, but a little bit of confusion on what to do with this. I then want to delete any files that aren't in the `filtered` list. The file names are identical to the dates but with `.csv` at the end. The issue here, I think is, that I'd have to iterate over files and delete files, but deleting from what I'm iterating through is bad.

Comment: to get the difference between the lists you can use: *set(list_of_dates) - set(valid_days)*.  I think its totally ok to iterate through this list and delete the specified files one by one.

Comment: I think you're right, I think the problem arises when you start deleted items from a list you're iterating over, if the item is one you've not reached yet.

Comment: Thats correct. Deleting items from the list you're iterating can lead to trouble. However, here, you are deliting "only" the files without changing the list.

Comment: Another quick question, this is going to be run daily. How could I change the `now = datetime(2014, 9, 17)` to use today's date instead of a specified date?

Comment: you can use *now = datetime.now()*

Comment: I have just realised when using this code that `valid_days` is actually showing the next 10 working days in the future, whereas I would like it to show the previous 14 working days.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be some confusion here, Joe.

If you are iterating through a list of strings that are filenames, yes it's bad to delete a string from the list. But it's *perfectly* safe to delete the named file from your hard drive. Assuming (of course) that the list does, in fact, contain files that you may want to delete. :)

Comment: This is what I suspected, and what I worked out eventually. But yes, this is exactly where the confusion was. I've already accepted an answer because he helped me with the other problem as well, but definitely upvoting as this is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

To delete things from a list you are iterating in you can do something using this structure:

```
list_of_files[:] = [file for file in list if not in dates_list]
```

To make the code more readable and add extra checks you can sobstitute `not in dates_list` with a function call:

```
def file_check(file, dates_list):
  if conditionyoulike:
    return true
  else:
    return false

list_of_files[:] = [file for file in list if file_check(file,dates_list)]
```